# How to building uber-JAR with all non-transtive dependencies?

Tags: maven

I have Maven project that consists of the following modules and submodules:

```
A
  B      (with external dependencies like junit, spring, etc.)
  C      (with external dependencies as well)
  A-all  (with B and C defined as dependencies)
```

I would like the last module to build uber-JAR containing both B and C jars. I tried to use `maven-assembly-plugin` with `jar-with-dependencies` desciptor but the ultimate jar contains also transitive dependencies, i.e. dependencies used by B and C.

How can I build jar with all non-transitive dependencies of A-all module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the `useTransitiveDependencies` flag of assembly plugin to false.